# AWS EC2 Instance Status Checks 1/2 checks passed ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, ubuntu-18.04, amazon-elb

I was trying to create AMIs(AMAZON MACHINE INSTANCE) using my live working EC2 instance. When I have done all the steps somehow my live EC2 stop working(**1/2 checks passed**, `Instance Status Checks 
 - These checks monitor your software and network configuration for this instance.`) with 504 Gateway time out. It also not working on CLI or Putty. It gives me port 22 timeout. 
I have checked Inbound & Outbound rules also. All port(22,80,443) is open publicly. Out bound is set to All port.
I dont understand what's preventing it to connect.

Comment: Do you have internet gateway attached to the VPC?

Comment: Yes it it attached!

Comment: What is your instance type?

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67337279/13126651

Answer (score 0):

System log should give you the reason for the failure. You can get the system log from

> Actions --> Instance settings --> Get system log.

Answer (score 0):

You can try restarting the instance state.

> Go to EC2 instances -> select the instance -> Click on Actions / Click
> on Instance state (On top) -> First try with reboot.
>
> If a reboot doesn't work then try Stop instance and then start the
> instance.