# How to fix a warning on status check of EC2 instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've created one EC2 account.
Then, there is one strange warning on status check in detail items of instance.

[image]

Comment: what kinf of feedback you exactly want?

Comment: Posted a solution  which will guide you on what kind of check has failed and how to troubleshoot.

Comment: @FannWong - you need to do more research. The screenshot is completely useless. As the answer indicates, you need to get specific check that failed. Then the solution might be obvious - or you may have a better questions. (I hate when people downvote without explanation ;)

Comment: Dont worry stackoverflow is a great place to learn, just keep in mind from next time explain your problem in such a way that its easier for people to help you give as much details as you can.

Comment: Hello, @fann I repost the answer. can you check the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Thre are 2 types of status check in ec2 done by aws: [system status checks and instance status checks.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html).

**System status checks monitor** the AWS systems on which your instance runs.
**Instance status checks monitor** the software and network configuration of your individual instance.

To view status checks using the AWS Management Console.

- Console -> select your instance -> `choose status check`.
  It should look like this
  [image]

docs says

> "If your instance has a failed status check, you typically must address the problem yourself (for example, by rebooting the instance or by making instance configuration changes). However, if your instance has a failed status check and has been unreachable for over 20 minutes, choose **Open support case** to submit a request for assistance."

to troubleshoot instance on your own [follow this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html)

Comment: Yes sure :).If you can accept this as an answer it will be much appreciated so that it may help others in the future.

Comment: It will still help others in the future if they see the answer, you got downvoted as @felix said, the explanation for your question was not up to mark, it wont help anybody if you just port a screenshot, actually you could have posted what kind of health check was failed so its easier for others to help you, keep in mind for next time :)
`you can still accept it as answer`, I already upvoted :) upvotes and downvotes depend on the total number of upvote or downvote it has received for example 3 downvotes but 1 upvote it will show -2 others -3.

Comment: @Jatin why do you delete my answer?

Comment: on stackoverflow we cannot delete somebody's else answer, so I didn't !